# Specifying a routerLink for a lazy loaded module component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In this demo app I have the following route in the lazy loaded books module:

```
{ path: 'collection', component: CollectionPageComponent },
```

And in the search component the following router link:

```
  <a routerLink="collection">Collections</a>
```

When hovering over the link it displays the path `books/collection`.  However when clicking it it routes to the 404 page.  Thoughts?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-temp-slice-demo-phase2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route

```
{ path: ':id', component: ViewBookComponent, resolve: { book: BookResolverService }}
```

is consuming your string `collection` as input to `id`.

To resolve this,

Put specific routes to the top i.e.

```
{ path: 'collection', component: CollectionPageComponent },
{ path: ':id', component: ViewBookComponent, resolve: { book: BookResolverService }}
```